# Mongo query $grouping

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, group

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQYTb.png)

I have docs like:

```
[{
  "_id":"6488628df934c73ca5734924",
  "category": "Activity & Sports",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "name": [
    {
      "_id":"648862f6f934c73ca5734a02",
      "tag": "Ziplining"
    },
    {
      "_id": "648862f6f934c73ca57349ff",
      "tag": "Yoga"
    }
]}]
```

And I want to group this into an array of objects, I just want to combine my category & subcategory into an object of an array.

```
[
    { 
     "_id":"6488628df934c73ca5734924",
      "category": "Activity & Sports",
    }
    {
      "_id":"648862f6f934c73ca5734a02",
      "tag": "Ziplining"
    },
    {
      "_id": "648862f6f934c73ca57349ff",
      "tag": "Yoga"
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.   What aggregation pipeline have you tried so far, and what has not worked?